# how to implement object-level private access in java

Tags: java, encapsulation

How could I make a member field private *to this specific object*?
i.e. this object can read and modify the value, but other objects of the same class cannot.

e.g.

```
class Person 
{
    // don't mind sharing these with other persons :
    private integer houseNumber;
    private integer telephoneNumber;

    // would like this to be *really private*
    // (only visible / modifiable to this instance)
    private integer bankBalance;


    // Lots of code for interaction with other persons:
    // (e.g. maintained by co-workers)

    void interact1(Person person)
    {
        //Lots of code
    }

    void interact2(Person person)
    {
        //Lots of code
    }

    //...

    void interactN(Person person)
    {
        //Lots of code
    }
}
```

I understand that Java's 'private' access means access is restricted to code in this class.
Conceptually all the code in the class is under my control so I am responsible for it.  It should be my responsibilty to control what Person objects do to other Person objects.

But say I have a large number of methods interacting with other persons, and I want the compiler to do the checking for me, rather than personally scouring the code.  Maybe this java file is shared with co-workers, and changes frequently.

My question is - how can I implement 'private to this object' access in Java?  Is there a sane / sensible way of achieving it?

EDIT - re-emphasis of goals

I want a few lines of class design / code, to guarantee that other Person objects can not read / write the bankBalance belonging to this instance.  I know it's not really designed for in Java - but that's part of my motivation, to see what is the cleanest way to achieve it in general.  I really want the compiler to enforce it - I'm not looking for a solution that involves auditing all the functions, making sure they only call the correct getter / access method.

Comment: You might be able to use AOP to do this. Advise your getters and setters to throw Exceptions or return some default value. This would require some security layer to know who/what is calling the method. Thread-locals might be helpful.

Comment: @Sotirios - the point is, with Java 'private' setting, there is no enforcement that code go via getters and setters.  e.g. in function interact1, there's nothing to stop code from directly accessing private members of the input parameter

Comment: You could make a superclass of `Person` that contains the private fields you have. Then make a `ManagedPerson` so that all interactions with attributes go through getters and setters. You can annotate those for AOP or do something like what Alberto suggests in his answer.

Comment: On a side note, a `Person` shouldn't check if they can see another `Person`'s info. The application should do those checks.

Comment: Encapsulate each `interact` code into a different object that does one type of interaction. Those will no longer see the privates of a `Person`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your purpose is to protect against accidents rather than malice, you could create a separate BankBalance class that keeps track of who owns the balance:

```
class BankBalance {
    private int bal;
    private Person belongsTo;
    public BankBalance (int initialBalance, Person belongsTo) {
        this.bal = initialBalance; this.belongsTo = belongsTo; 
    }
    public int getBalance (Person calledBy) {
        if (calledBy != belongsTo) throw new RuntimeException ("no peeking");
        return bal;
    }
}

class Person {
    private BankBalance bal;

    void checkBalance () {
        if (bal.getBalance(this) > 1000) ...
    }
}
```

Any use of `getBalance` would need the caller to pass `this`.  I think this might make it harder to *accidentally* write code that accessess another Person's balance.  You could also make BankBalance a nested class, and check `calledBy != Person.this` rather than needing an explicit `belongsTo` field, but that would allow `interact1` to refer to `person2.bal.bal` (making `bal` private in BankBalance still wouldn't prevent the enclosing class from accessing it).  Maybe that's still good enough to prevent accidents.

Comment: +1 I like the interface, pass in an object and get back the correct balance.  Still it's not quite satisfying, seems more like security by obscurity.  I could nest inner classes called person.dontLookAtThis.noReallyThisMeansYou.bankBalance ... this would prevent developers calling it by mistake.  I'm looking for a solution where, with a few lines of code / design, I can be sure that the compiler will check for me and guarantee no read / writes.

Comment: to be clear - my issue with this solution is that BankBalance and BankBalance.bal are still available as private members on my object.  So the problem 'other objects can access my private field' is still there, just wrapped a level deeper.

Comment: The term "Security by obscurity" usually refers to protection from deliberate attack.  I don't think there's any programmatic solution for that, if you have programmers who have access to the code but are willing to use it for criminal purposes.  Even a new language feature wouldn't help.  For the purpose of preventing coding errors, if you make it difficult to commit certain kinds of errors, that should be enough.  However, it seems feasible to add the kind of language feature you're asking for.  I wonder where would be a good place to suggest a future change ...

Comment: ok 'security' is going too far I suppose.  But I would like the compiler to enforce the solution.  I'm thinking about something like your interface, but in an object external to the class...maybe a Bank class.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone pointed out there is no real way of doing this. You could do something like a getter of the form

```
private int getBankBalance(Object caller) {
     if (caller == this) {
          return bankBalance;
     } else {
          throw new RuntimeException("GTFO");
     }
}
```

and then enforcing that all access be done through `object.getBankBalance(this)`.

However this does not stop people from accessing the `bankBalance` directly or calling `object.getBankBalance(object)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an arraylist of balances that will contain each Persons balance.
Something like this:

```
static int instances = 0;
private int thisInstance = 0; 
private List<Integer> balances = new Arraylist<>();

public Person() {
   instances++;
   thisInstance = instances;
   balances.add(thisInstance, new Integer(0));
}
```

Then whenever you have code that interacts with the `bankBalance` you just return the same element as the instance that called it.

For example, if the fifth instance tried to get it's balance, the method would return the fifth balance in the array.

For example:

```
private int getBankBalance() {
   return balances.get(thisInstance).intValue();
}
```

This will make it so anyone attempting to get their bank balance is only returned their balance, and they can't see anyone elses balance.

Comment: I would like every Person to have a separate bankBalance, without being able to peek at each others bankBalance

Comment: This method would not work since thisInstance would always refer to the instance in which the method is being called, not the instance that is calling the method. That or I'm reading something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the direction you are taking is the correct one, if I were you I would try to see things from a different angle, it is a weird requirement the one you're asking.

You cannot achieve that if what you need is forbid the property access from other objects. You could do it if you specify a getter for it and use that to reference the property.

An instance is identified by its attributes, so you could write a method that checks for certain properties and then use it to determine if a certain object could access that property accessor.

So to sum up it would be something like this:

```
private boolean isBankBalanceAccessible() {
    // check that properties are those you want,
    // for example only when houseNumber is 1234567890
    return houseNumber == 1234567890;
}

private int getBankBalance() {
    if (isBankBalanceAccessible()) {
        return bankBalance;
    } else {
        // maybe throw here?
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on what entity controls the object creation.

Comment: What do you mean? What would be the case this would not work in your opinion?

Comment: I guess it depends on what checks are done in `isBankBalanceAccessible()`. Those properties have to be outside the control of the user.

Comment: the thing is, nothing will force all the code in those 'interact' methods to run a check before accessing. Nothing will even force them to use getter methods.  There is nothing to stop them from looking directly at the private data member.  That's what I want to prevent - I'd like a simple code structure/pattern to prevent those 'interact' methods from peeking at bankBalances that belong to other Persons.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this...

```
     void interact1(Person person)
      {
         if(this==person)
          {
             person.bankBalance
             // Do here with the balance of the objecct which calls this function
          }


          //rest code here
      }
```

Hope it works..!!

Comment: Better way is to use Object class equals method to check similar Id's of object...!!